# If an $n{\times}n$ diagonal matrix, $A$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $AB=BA$; then $B$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, diagonalization

I've been trying to go through [this](https://doi.org/10.1002/mana.19961780107) paper for the past month, but I'm stuck on Lemma 4.4

So, the argument goes as follows:
g is an integer $n{\times}n$ matrix with irreducible characteristic polynomial (over $\mathbb Z[x]$).
and $\psi$ is any real $n{\times} n$ matrix that commutes with $g$ (so it has to be diagonal)

Now, the author says

> "The space of complex solutions, $L_c \subset M_n(\mathbb C)$ of the equation $\psi g=g \psi$ with unknown vector $\psi \in M_n(\mathbb C)$ has also dimension $n$. It follows that the space of real solutions $L_r = L_c \cap M_n( \mathbb R)$ is $n$-dimensional over $\mathbb R$ since the coefficients of the equation are reals."

I know that they're simultaneously diagonalizable and that the columns of $g$ span $\mathbb R^n$ i.e. an n-dimensional vector space, but I don't understand why the same must be true for $\psi$, because, for all I know, it could very well be the $0$ matrix.

Now, I think I'm missing something obvious here, but it's beaten me for more than a week now, so I've thrown in the towel, and here I come seeking some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $g$ is irreducible over $\mathbb C$, so its roots are all distinct and it is diagonalizable, and is diagonal in a basis of eigenvectors.  The system
$\psi g - g \psi = 0$ has kernel of dimension $n$ (over $\mathbb C$), the solutions being
all matrices that are diagonal in this basis.  Now the entries of $g$ are real, so that system (as an $n^2 \times n^2$ system for the entries $\psi_{ij}$ of $\psi$) has real coefficients.  A real $n^2 \times n^2$ system with kernel of dimension $n$ has a basis with real entries, which could e.g. be obtained by row reduction.

Comment: My apologies, but  $n^2 \times n^2 $ system how ? both matrices have just n values each.

Comment: They are diagonal in a basis of eigenvectors, but those are complex.  Instead use the "standard" basis.  The system is $\sum_{k=1}^n \psi_{ik} g_{kj} - \sum_{k=1}^n g_{ik} \psi_{kj} = 0$ for $i,j = 1 \ldots n$.